# Linq join to 1:n relation with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I am new here in the forum and I am from germany because my English is not the best. I hope you understand me.

I have a question about linq in Entity Framework Core.

I have these tables:

**TB_Account**

```
AccountId
LoginName
Password
```

**TB_AccountAccountData**

```
AccountId
AccountDataId
```

**TB_AccountData**

```
AccountDataId
EmailAddress
ModuleId
...
```

This is my `DbContext` class:

```
internal class LoginSystemContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<TB_Account> Accounts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
            => options.UseSqlServer("Data Source=LoginSystem.db");
}
```

And these is one of my model classes:

```
internal partial class TB_Account
{
    #region properties...
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LoginName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TB_AccountData> AccountData { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

Now I want to get a dataset with criteria below:

```
LoginName AND EmailAddress AND ModuleId
```

My problem is, I don't know how to do the join statement to the `TB_AccountData`.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) to load related data:

```
using(LoginSystemContext db = new LoginSystemContext()){
var account = db.Accounts.Include("AccountData").Select(x => new {LoginName, EmailAddress, x.Accounts.FirstOrDefault().ModuleId});}
```

Goodluck!!